# From excel web addin (Task pane), using javascript shared runtime, can we create a new powerpoint file, add some content and save it?

Tags: office-js

I am developing an excel web addin and have also setup javascript shared runtime. In this environment, is it possible to create a new powerpoint file, add some content to it including images and save it to local computer? If yes, it would be great if I can get a sample code for how to communicate with powerpoint from excel addin.

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, creating powerpoint file in excel addin is not supported now.

You could go to [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) to submit a new feature request.

Sorry for the inconvenience.